# Pytorch and data augmentation: how to augmentate data with blur, rotations, etc

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to do some data augmentation with Pytorch, but i don't know the libraries very well:

I tried this:

```
def gaussian_blur(img):
    image = np.array(img)
    image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(65,65),10)
    new_image = image_blur
    im = Image.fromarray(new_image) 
    return im


data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomRotation([-8,+8]),
        transforms.Lambda(gaussian_blur),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0, contrast=0.4, saturation=0, hue=0),
        transforms.Compose([transforms.Lambda(lambda x : x + torch.randn_like(x))]),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomRotation([-8,+8]),
        transforms.Lambda(gaussian_blur),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0, contrast=0.4, saturation=0, hue=0),
        transforms.Compose([transforms.Lambda(lambda x : x + torch.randn_like(x))]),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}
```

Because the effects i want to do are: `gaussian blur/rotation/contrast/gamma+random noise`

But i have errors considering several aspects, like the size of the images doesn't match.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply Gausian blur there is also already a pytorch class for:

```
torchvision.transforms.GaussianBlur(kernel_size, sigma=(0.1, 2.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If input images are of different sizes, you have different options, depending on your project. For example, you can just resize your image using `transforms.Resize((w, h))` or `transforms.CenterCrop((w, h))`. There are several options for resizing your images so all of them have the same size, check [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#transforms-on-torch-tensor).

Also, you can create your own transforms instead of using Lambda. You could do something like this

```
def GaussianBlur(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, std_dev):
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.std_dev = std_dev

    def forward(self, img):
        image = np.array(img)
        image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, self.kernel_size, self.std_dev)
        return Image.fromarray(image_blur)


data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.CenterCrop(416),
        transforms.RandomRotation([-8,+8]),
        GaussianBlur((65, 65), 10),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0, contrast=0.4, saturation=0, hue=0),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda x : x + torch.randn_like(x)),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.CenterCrop(416),
        transforms.RandomRotation([-8,+8]),
        GaussianBlur((65, 65), 10),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0, contrast=0.4, saturation=0, hue=0),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda x : x + torch.randn_like(x)),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}
```

I removed a useless Compose inside the Compose, and in this example used a CenterCrop for getting a 416 x 416 image. If you have other errors, it might help to post them.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-24-77d6a33d043f>", line 3
    def gaussianBlur(nn.Module):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: By the way, i'm using this tut: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html , and i'm replacing the Load Data content

Comment: File "<ipython-input-28-0cb6e2be39ca>", line 11, in <lambda>
    transforms.Lambda(lambda x : x + torch.randn_like(x)),
TypeError: randn_like(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Image

Comment: Oh yeah, place "ToTensor" before the Lambda, check edit

Comment: Is taking REALLY long to do one epoch.. is it normal?

Comment: Make sure to use the GPU and more than one worker, in the dataloader you can define the number of workers (I usually use 4).